# JPA inserting based on @MapKey

Tags: jpa, dictionary, eclipselink

I have the following field in my entity (MyEntity):

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
@MapKey(name="localeForDB")
private Map<String, MyEntityTranslations> translations;
```

MyEntityTranslations looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MY_ENTITY_TRANSLATIONS")
public class MyEntityTranslations extends CustomTranslations
{
    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;

    //..getters and setters
}
```

And finally CustomTranslations looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class CustomTranslations
{
    @Id
    protected Long id;
    @Transient
    protected Locale locale;

    @Column(name="LOCALE", nullable=false)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @Id
    protected String getLocaleForDB()
    {
        return locale.toString();
    }

    protected void setLocaleForDB(String localeFromDB)
    {
        //logic for creating a Locale object from a String
    }
}
```

Everything works great when I'm pulling data out of the database. I get a MyEntity and the map is populated as I would expect. However, when I try to insert data (save a MyEntity), it errors out on me. This is what is in the logs:

```
[EL Fine]: 2012-09-04 23:40:19.989--ClientSession(101408113)--Connection(1411623120)--Thread(Thread[http-8080-1,5,main])--select nextval(MY_ENTITY_SEQ_GEN)
[EL Fine]: 2012-09-04 23:40:20.048--ClientSession(101408113)--Connection(1411623120)--Thread(Thread[http-8080-1,5,main])--INSERT INTO MY_ENTITY (ID, STUFF, FOR, MY_ENTITY,) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [1, foo1, foo2, foo3]
[EL Fine]: 2012-09-04 23:40:20.13--ClientSession(101408113)--Connection(1411623120)--Thread(Thread[http-8080-1,5,main])--INSERT INTO MY_ENTITY_TRANSLATIONS (ID, LOCALE, PROP1, PROP2) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [null, en_US, My Prop1, My Prop2]
[EL Fine]: 2012-09-04 23:40:20.135--ClientSession(101408113)--Thread(Thread[http-8080-1,5,main])--SELECT 1
[EL Warning]: 2012-09-04 23:40:20.139--UnitOfWork(1394902291)--Thread(Thread[http-8080-1,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO MY_ENTITY_TRANSLATIONS (ID, LOCALE, PROP1, PROP2) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [null, en_US, My Prop1, My Prop2]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.foo.MyEntityTranslations@53fd3a3b)
Sep 4, 2012 11:40:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
```

Now, before I trying saving the `MyEntity` object, I see in the map that the id field for the `MyEntityTranslations` entry is null. I understand this, because `MyEntity` itself doesn't have an id yet. The id field in `MyEntity` has the following annotation:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="MY_ENTITY_SEQ_GEN")
```

So, it gets its id from the sequence when it's inserted. My question is how do I need to annotate the map so that that id gets on the `MyEntityTranslations` record as well? I've tried different attributes on the `@JoinColumn`, but nothing seems to work. I'm a bit of a JPA newbie, so I'm probably missing something obvious. I want to keep all the JPA implementation independent, but if it matters, I am using EclipseLink 2.3.2.

Based on the suggestion below, I changed my CustomTranslations to look like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class CustomTranslations<T>
{
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID")
    protected T translationsFor;
    @Transient
    protected Locale locale;

    @Column(name="LOCALE", nullable=false)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @Id
    protected String getLocaleForDB()
    {
        return locale.toString();
    }

    protected void setLocaleForDB(String localeFromDB)
    {
        //logic for creating a Locale object from a String
    }
}
```

And then my Map in `MyEntity` looks like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="translationsFor", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@MapKey(name="localeForDB")
private Map<String, MyEntityTranslations> translations;
```

I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding something, but I'm still getting the exact same error as before when trying to save a MyEntity instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a @ManyToOne back in your MyEntityTranslations.  Your @OneToMany should use  a mappedBy not a @JoinColumn.

Remove the id from CustomTranslations and instead add a @ManyToOne to MyEntity with the @JoinColumn and @Id on it.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany

and,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#JPA_2.0

Comment: I updated my question with my attempt at what you are saying. I'm still getting the same error. Can you shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you set the value of the translationsFor in the CustomTranslations before persisting it

Comment: Yes, of course. The library I'm using to initially populate the entity doesn't magically do it for me. :) Once I got that populated it works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should result in an error, because you have 2 mappings that control the "ID" field in the "MY_ENTITY_TRANSLATIONS" table.  The first being the ID mapping in the CustomTranslations class, the second being the OneToMany mapping in MyEntity.  You can only have 1 writable, and I suggest you make it one accessible from within the class mapped to the table to avoid other problems.

The easiest way to do what you want is to make your OneToMany a bidirectional OneToMany.  That means add a ManyToOne mapping in CustomTranslations back to MyEntity that uses the "ID" field as the join column, and then mark the OneToMany as mapped by this new mapping.  JPA allows you making this new ManyToOne as the ID for the CustomTranslations, so you can remove the Long id, or you can keep it and use the @MapsId annotation so that JPA knows that the value from the referenced MyEntity is to be used in the Long id field as well.  Something like:

```
   @Id protected Long id;  
   @MapsId(value="id")
   @ManyToOne
   MyEntity myEntityBackReference;
```

You will need to maintain the bidirectional relationship instead of just the collection, but this will be implementation independent.

Comment: How would the @MapsId work with the locale that I also want as part of the primary key?